# Why do we need private variables?

Tags: javascript, private-members

What are they for and how do we make it? Can you give me an example?

Comment: What are you calling private variables? Why are you asking this question? Please be a bit more descriptive.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To avoid collisions with multiple libraries, for example.

Say they both use a variable commonly used such as `data`. If both libraries use private variables it's all fine:

```
var lib1 = (function() {
    var data;

    return {
        get: function()  { return data },
        set: function(v) { data = v }
    };
})();

// Supposed to do something different:
var lib2 = (function() {
    var data;

    return {
        get: function()  { return data },
        set: function(v) { data = v }
    };
})();

lib1.set(123);
lib2.set(456);
lib1.get(); // 123
lib2.get(); // 456
```

However suppose they don't use private variables but global ones like this:

```
var lib1 = (function() {
    return {
        get: function()  { return data },
        set: function(v) { data = v }
    };
})();

// Supposed to do something different:
var lib2 = (function() {
    return {
        get: function()  { return data },
        set: function(v) { data = v }
    };
})();

lib1.set(123);
lib2.set(456);
lib1.get(); // 456 - overwritten by lib2. lib1 might not work properly anymore.
lib2.get(); // 456
```

So `lib1.get()` will fetch the same data as `lib2.get()`.

This example is too obvious of course but to stay safe it's a good practice to use private variables.

Answer (score 3):

Variables are encapsulated within a class to stop their names colliding. These can be public or private. Sometimes there is a need to make sure that variables are only changed using the functions that set them. For example the parts of a date would need to be verified to stop someone setting an invalid date such aas February 45th.

```
var factorial = (function(){
    var precog = [1,1];// ===undefined for other indices, N = undefined || N
    return function(y){  
        return precog[y] || (precog[y]=y*arguments.callee(y-1));
    };
})();
```

Here is a JavaScript function with a private precog. This stores previously calculated values and it is private to stop them being manipulated.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there are *multiple* reasons for **namespaces**. One way I understand it is: `private`, `protected`, and `public` expressions help a lot in *team environments* so that other devs don't end up using *methods* you didn't intend them to. That being said, you only use `private` when methods or properties only need to be accessed by that same object. Use `protected` when you need an inheriting class to carry that same functionality and use `public` when an object of a different class needs to access your object.

eg:

Class `Victim` has

- private method haveAnxiety()
- public property appearsToBeRich:Boolean

Class `Robber` has

- private method profile(obj:Victim)
- private method rob(obj:Victim)

`Robber->profile()` will need to access `Victim->appearsToBeRich`. If `Victim->appearsToBeRich` returns `true`, then that `Victim` object will get *robbed*. a `Robber` object never needs to run `Victim->haveAnxiety` as the `Victim` will run `this->haveAnxiety()` as soon as that `Victim` object starts getting robbed.

Granted, real world examples are a **LOT** more complex than my example (and I hope they are much more *graceful*). Anyway, I hope that helps.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is about JavaScript.